# Good free online app engine

Tags: web-applications, cloud

I have a non commercial project I'm working on in my free time. It will be a web based app.

I know I could go the whole PHP or ASP MVC route and find a host. I would like to save some cash though and avoid paying for hosting, or using an unreliable free host, or something cluttered with ads.

I basically need to develop an online app which will have a database, although I don't mind if I need to interact using orm's.

Google Apps spring to mind, but before I dive into it, are there any alternatives? This should include the framework, hosting and db. All free! Reason why I'm not that keen to jump into Google Apps is they don't cater for MS developers i.e: C# / VB.net guys.

Lastly its not a giant app my any means.

Comment: Pick any two: Good, Fast, Cheap  :)

Answer (score 1):

Amazon is currently offering some [free services](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) although they are Linux servers on EC2.  If you need windows you could just use an [Amazon Micro Instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing) they run about $0.03/hour, and can be powered down when not needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Heroku](http://heroku.com/) is a cloud service with Ruby on Rails integration. It based on Amazon Web Services and offers free plan.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) provides free cloud engine, although limited to 3 gears (software stacks).